# Subset by multiple variables?

Tags: sas

My dataset looks like this for professional claims for patients:

```
data professionalclaims;
input patient_ID ICN DOS Proc_code;
datalines
1 10 3nov2012 7686
1 11 3nov2012 6554
1 12 3nov2012 4543
2 13 13nov2012 5959
2 14 13nov2012 5454
3 15 18nov2012 5444
;
run;
```

Where ICN is the individual claim, DOS is the date of service, and proc_code is the procedure for what is done.

I am interested in finding out how many individual claims a person has in one visit, ie how many individual ICNs a person has for one DOS.

Comment: PROC FREQ or PROC MEANS seem like useful procedures here, depending on exactly what you're looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data professionalclaims;
input patient_ID ICN DOS date9. Proc_code;
datalines;
1 10 3nov2012 7686
1 11 3nov2012 6554
1 12 3nov2012 4543
2 13 13nov2012 5959
2 14 13nov2012 5454
3 15 18nov2012 5444
;
run;

proc sql;
     select patient_id, DOS format = date9., count(distinct ICN) as Ind_claim_Count
     from professionalclaims
     group by patient_id, DOS;
    quit;
```

Working: You will have to group by patient_id and DOS to get count of individual claims a person has at each visit.